# EU discount product regulation - Omnibus

Tags: product, pricebook, commerce-cloud, b2c

I have to update pricing information display: For any promotional activation, when a promotional pricing is available, pricing from the last 30 days should be displayed. Is there an existing cartridge for this purpouse? Is this possible without implementing a third party application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is one available: https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/eu-price-indication

Though this is meant as a starting point.